# Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault при выполнении кода

Tags: python, simple-draw

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# (цикл for)
import simple_draw as sd
sd.resolution = (1200, 600)
def wall():
    y2 = 100  # Верхний левый край кирпича. Равен 0 так как каждый цикл ряд должен подниматься
    row = 0  # Переменная для подсчёта циклов
    for y1 in range(100, 300, 20):  # Цикл для постройки кирпичей в высоту
        y2 += 20  # Поднимаем ряд кирпичей
        row += 1  # Кладём первый ряд кирпичей
        if row % 2 == 0:  # Условие. Если цикл нечётный, то сдвиг кирпичей. Если чётный - оставить на прежнем месте
            x2 = 300
            range_x = range(300, 700, 40)  # Диапазон выкладывания кирпичей для чётного ряда
        else:
            x2 = 280
            range_x = range(280, 660, 40)  # Диапазон выкладывания кирпичей для нечётного ряда
        for x1 in range_x:  # Кладём кирпичи в ширину
            x2 += 40
            sd.rectangle(left_bottom=sd.get_point(x1, y1), right_top=sd.get_point(x2, y2),
                         color=sd.COLOR_ORANGE, width=2)
            sd.rectangle(left_bottom=sd.get_point(280, 100), right_top=sd.get_point(700, 300),
                         color=sd.COLOR_ORANGE, width=2)
            if sd.user_want_exit():
                break
            # sd.sleep(0.1)


wall()

def roof():
    point1 = sd.get_point(280, 300)
    point2 = sd.get_point(490, 400)
    point3 = sd.get_point(700, 300)
    sd.polygon([point1, point2, point3], color=sd.COLOR_DARK_RED, width=0)


roof()

def land():
    sd.rectangle(left_bottom=sd.get_point(0, 0), right_top=sd.get_point(1200, 100), color=sd.COLOR_DARK_ORANGE,
                 width=0)


land()
sd.pause()
```

когда я импортирую в другой модуль все функции из этого кода - то всё работает. Если пытаюсь создать отдельно модуль land и по всем правилам импортировать функцию land у меня вылезает ошибка

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault

Current thread 0x00002038 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\simple_draw.py", line 390 in rectangle
  File "D:\python developer\5. \u041c\u043e\u0434\u0443\u043b\u0438 \u0438 \u043f\u0430\u043a\u0435\u0442\u044b\\u0414\u043e\u043f. \u043c\u0430\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0430\u043b\u044b\lesson_005\paintings\house.py", line 21 in wall
  File "D:\python developer\5. \u041c\u043e\u0434\u0443\u043b\u0438 \u0438 \u043f\u0430\u043a\u0435\u0442\u044b\\u0414\u043e\u043f. \u043c\u0430\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0430\u043b\u044b\lesson_005\paintings\masterpiece.py", line 10 in <module>

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Comment: А вы установили сам модуль? Через pip install?

Comment: `Segmentation Fault` - это или памяти не хватает, или какая-то совсем уж суровая ошибка в библиотеках. Очень странно.

Comment: Да, причём у меня памяти на ноуте 8гб и я не ограничивал pycharm в ресурсах

Comment: Вообще `PyCharm` и сам ресурсы нехило кушает так то )  Вы из него код запускаете?

Comment: @ЯнПопов 1 - нужно чтобы хватало ресурсов не Pycharm, а интерпретатору python. 2 - попробуйте максимально сократить код, чтобы остался минимальный код, на котором воспроизводится ошибка, условно до инициализации и рисования одного rectangle. Возможно что-то с параметрами не так.

Comment: Да, а питон то сам не 32-битный случайно? Ну, мало ли.

Comment: @CrazyElf, питон и винда 64 бита. Интерпретатор версии 3.7.

Comment: Подумал что дело может быть в том, что pycharm не может накладывать рисунки один на другой. Происходит конфликт координат.  Добавил в функции параметры, в которых указал координаты и при импортировании и дальнейшем вызове прописал эти координаты в параметрах. не помогло. В одном файле все функции работают, я ещё несколько добавил и всё чётко. ChatGPT не смог мне помочь, пишет, что всё должно работать. И ещё... Почему, если я не вызываю функцию в том файле, где она написана - она не рисуется при импорте её в отдельный файл. В уроке была функция(правда, простая) работала и без её доп. вызова